# Programmatically Change Pager "Items to Display" value?

Tags: 7, views, paging

I would like to create a custom form to allow a website admin to quickly change the number of "Items to Display" for a particular block display for a particular view, but I don't have a clue how to change this value programmatically on my own, besides the views ui?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you retrieve the view with **views_get_view()**, then you alter the value, then you save the retrieved view with **views_save_view()** like this:

```
function my_custom_function($view, $num) {
  $myview = views_get_view('$view', TRUE);

  $myview->display['default']->display_options['pager']['options']['items_per_page'] = $num;
  views_save_view($myview);

  // Clear the cache for the pager
  $cache = $myview . ':block:results:';
  cache_clear_all($cache, 'cache_views_data', TRUE);
}
```

I also included a little snippet at the end of the custom function to clear the appropriate cache bin if need be.

Answer (score 0):

im not sure of any 3rd party module that allows easy "override the # of items per page". I've done this task a few times for View displays using core drupal apis.

Basically:

1. you use hook_views_pre_build to programmatically alter the view.
2. Use a custom variable to store your items per page value.
3. Make a simple admin page to allow a site administrator alter the value.

EDIT: amended to different views hook function.

Comment: tenken, how would I "use hook_views_pre_render to programmatically alter the view"?

I tried:

`function glue_views_pre_render(&$view) {
  if ($view->name == 'news') {
    $view->query->pager->options['items_per_page'] = '2';
  }
}`

to no avail.

Comment: im catching a ride soon. try the same thing in hook_views_pre_build() ... what you have looks correct. http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_build/7

Comment: I think you would be better using `hook_views_pre_build()` and then somthing like that `$view->items_per_page = variable_get('custom_view_items', 10);`