# Embed Views remove pager

Tags: views, paging

I have embedded view in a node with following code:

```
<?php
 $view = views_get_view('articles');
 $view->set_items_per_page(1);
 $view->set_offset(2);
 print $view->preview('page');
 $view->destroy();
?>
```

I just need to display only one specific row (that's why I'm using offset). I couldn't find a way to retrieve one specific row with any other method.

This code is acceptable but it has pager because that view has more than one row.
Is there a way to remove pager like in Views UI? In Views there is a option to not use a pager but "Display a specified number of items".

I would like to remove it completely from code without CSS.

Comment: The simplest way might be to create a second display via the Views UI (call it `offset_2` for descriptive purposes) that doesn't have a pager in it, eg, selecting `Display a specified number of items` instead of `Paged Output` and then calling that in your `print $view->preview('offset_2');`

Comment: Yes, it's  possible to do that way but I wanted to do this programaticaly. I want to optimize page as much as possible because that page has already too much queries.

Comment: It would be much better to do it from single display. I will need to create about 10 displays. it will clutter views ui. Reason I'm doing this is to have about 10 blocks placed on diferrent places on page. Think of metro ui.

Comment: well you can always modify the pager settings in a pre_render() or pre_build() hook much like you are doing in your question with other settings.  google will be your friend here as there are many options.  http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/86007/change-views-pager-programmatically?rq=1 might be a good starting place.

Comment: you could also look at somehow overriding the appropriate theme template for this view.  if you look in there you will see the pager is creating by just printing `$pager` so if you can figure out a way to target this instantiation of the view, you could just comment it out there.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having to hide the specific pager with css in the case I did what you are trying to do...

Comment: I'm aware of display:none but I would like to remove it from code. CSS is last resort.

Comment: I understand that, I am saying that I was unable to find another way after much research...hopefully you can, unfortunately I don't think you will...

Comment: If I stumble across anything I will certainly post it here.