# Theme views pager

Tags: views, theming, paging

I need to theme views pager, but I can't find the way to do it. 
For example - Instead of printing 'last page' I need print the last page number. 
I tried to use Drupal's `theme_pager` with the pager array from the 'view' object, but it returns an empty string.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Solved :) - Following [Change views pager programmatically](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/86007/change-views-pager-programmatically) .

**Example code:**
(In `hook_views__pre_render`)

```
if( !empty($view->query->pager->options) ) {
  $last_page = ceil($view->query->pager->total_items / $view->query->pager->options['items_per_page']);
  $view->query->pager->options['tags']['last'] = $last_page;
}
```