# why views items per page set to specific values

Tags: views, paging

Why does the Views module accep uses the number of items per page that is in pre-defined sets like 5, 10, 25, 50, and doesn't accept values outside those values?

I know how to change it; I just need an explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be brutally simple: Because someone thought it to be good UX, maintainers agreed, and no one convinced them other way since then. That's all to it.

---

There are many reasons for drop-down instead of text field. For example simplicity. User cannot enter bad values, so there is no need for bad value handling. Testing - you can programatically set other amounts, all right, but there you have ones they tested their module for, and take some responsibility that they work properly. Of course, maybe someone simply liked it that way. No way to know for sure what was the most important part in this decision.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using `views_pag_views_pre_build()`

```
function views_pag_views_pre_build(&$view) {
    if ($view->name == "pagination") {
            $view->init_pager();
            $view->set_items_per_page('10');

    }
}
```

Reference [Human Love](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/86007/change-views-pager-programmatically)

Comment: I am not asking about how to do it, but why?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that argument passed to `set_items_per_page` should be an integer. Of course PHP will cast it silently, but anyway no need for string constant where integer value is needed.

Answer (score 0):

the function names dont look correct here for the latest version of D8

should be

```
$view->initPager();
$view->setItemsPerPage(10); // or any other integer value
```